# Yosemite character encoding different leading to garbage in MySQL-based site

Tags: php, mysql, excel, osx-yosemite, navicat

I use Macs.

For years I have been updating the content of an ExpressionEngine website based on PHP/MySQL. This process involves linking the content of InDesign pages to a Filemaker database, exporting specified fields to an Excel spreadsheet and using Navicat to update corresponding fields in the MySQL database. I know from experiments in linking Filemaker directly to MySQL that character encoding is a minefield.

The process I have outlined has always worked OK, provided in the Navicat import step I specify that the Excel spreadsheet is using Mac OS Roman encoding. This year, however, the result of the updating was garbage where I should have accented characters or fancy "typesetting" characters - en rules, inverted commmas etc.

What had changed? Well, I am using a new Mac, running Yosemite. I still have my old iMac, now in use as a second display, so I went back to that. Result: perfect. No garbage.

I have of course checked that the Excel file's text looks OK. (I am using the same file on both Macs, shared via Dropbox.) I'm running the same version of Navicat on both Macs.

So what is Yosemite doing to cause Navicat to stuff different characters into MySQL? And how can I stop it?

Chris

Comment: What kind of text are you expecting and what kind of text are you getting? Are you using different versions of Excel? Some default to Mac Roman1 encoding.

Comment: I'm expecting accented French characters and I'm getting black diamond shapes. As I said, I am using a single Excel file as the data source, shared via Dropbox. The old Mac does the update fine, the new one gives the problem.

I'm in the UK, and leaving my desk for the night now ...